# "One buttock-playing"; A musical terminology by Benjamin Zander, How should I translate into a non porn phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, terminology

I found the phrase "one-buttock playing" in the transcript of Benjamin Zander: The Transformative power of classical music on TED talk (min 11:26) http://www.ted.com/talks/benjamin_zander_on_music_and_passion/transcript?language=en. To translate "one-buttock playing into my native language will produce an impolite phrase. How should I do? I haven't found any musical term related to that phrase.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I am afraid such questions will not be accepted here. This platform is for enhancing your knowledge and polishing your skills regarding English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about choosing non-offensive translations of offensive English terminology.

Comment: pls read my edit @RuchirM

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That's musical terminology used by Benjamin Zander in his speech on TED talk.

Comment: @student: Based on half a decade of violin lessons and a musically literate upbringing, I'm reasonably sure that's *not* actually standard musical terminology. So I'm assuming it's a deliberate joke that native speakers would be expected to get: that, while it's not normal terminology, it's used as such. user3169's reference seems to explain why it's used.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: what does Benjamin mean by that context? does it mean: he could easily play the partiture?

Comment: I see no reason why this question is unacceptable.  @student is attempting to understand an idiosyncratic English characterization.  He or she is not asking for a translation.

Comment: *To translate "one-buttock playing into my native language will produce an impolite phrase.* -- This is strange. I'm sure that your language must allow you to come up with euphemistic expressions for "buttock" (and by extension "one-buttock playing"), unless mentioning "buttock" is considered taboo or rude in your culture in whatsoever manner (which I very much doubt--how else can doctors refer to that body part?)

Comment: This question can be saved by just rewording to request an understanding of meaning in context rather than "a translation".  I provided the answer below; "buttock" is not being used offensively at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes incorrect assumptions that can't be clearly answered, and asks for a translation/rephrasing of the speaker's chosen words that have a clear non-literal meaning in context.

Comment: Voting to close because I agree with 100% with @user3169.  The idea of finding a different phrase *for the purpose of translation* is complex and involves various skills, a [Theory of Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_studies) which is a very specific discipline.  It's simply unanswerable relative to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

Zander is saying that when one is inspired by the music, it is of a piece and not just a series of notes to be mechanically played with metronomic emphases.  When such an inspiration takes hold, it moves the body of the player, who can no longer sit immobile except for his hands, i.e., he can no longer sit with both buttocks glued to the seat.

Zander is being facetious and serious at the same time.

Comment: I don't see how your answer is applicable to the young student who starts at age 8 and becomes a one-buttock player at age 12.  Clearly, the student doesn't have to "lean over" to play the music, since he plays the notes, albeit in an uninspired way, from ages 8 to 11.  I also don't see how your answer applies to the pianist that Zander got to move from his stationery position so that the music could "flow out."  There's no indication that the pianist was playing anything with bass chords.

Comment: I added the reference  to his metaphor spoken at 3:19.  Note that I didn't even know about this at first.  And my answer clearly indicates **exactly that**: at the end, he leans onto one buttock for the final chord with shoulders over his hands, which is in a deep bass position.   However, I think I was a bit too harsh in my first comment, which I have removed.  We're actually saying the same thing.  I'm simply being more specific in that "one buttock" actually does mean "one buttock" in this piece, in addition to the symbolic meaning.

Comment: +1 I would like to say that IMO, this answer is also correct.  But I think Zander is saying that there's still a need to be sure that form (body position) is *properly* conveying the function (musical meaning).  It's not just letting the music take over the body; it's allowing the body to move properly according to the meaning of the music.  The former is just wild abandon, the latter is mind/body harmony.  Zander is promoting mind/body harmony (as opposed to the mind ruling the body).

Comment: The phrase 'moved by the music' has two meanings - a physical one and an emotional one. Zander is talking about an emotional reaction to the music being reflected in a physical reaction by the player. Clap your hands, tap your toes, click your fingers, sit on one buttock.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video to see what he meant.  It's a call-back to a prior metaphor that he presented at 3:19:

- I don't know how we got into this position. (Laughter) **I didn't say, "I'm going to move my shoulder over, my body." No, the music pushed me over, which is why I call it one-buttock playing.** (Music) It can be the other buttock. (Music) You know, a gentleman was once watching a presentation I was doing, when I was working with a young pianist. He was the president of a corporation in Ohio. I was working with this young pianist, and said, "The trouble with you is you're a two-buttock player. You should be a one-buttock player." I moved his body while he was playing. And suddenly, the music took off. It took flight. The audience gasped when they heard the difference. Then I got a letter from this gentleman. He said, "I was so moved. I went back and I transformed my entire company into a one-buttock company." (Laughter)

The phrase is being used to describe how one should (in his opinion) allow the music to move you physically while you play.  It's a euphemism of his philosophy, which is probably something like "form follows function".

You don't have to be a piano player to understand, but it does help to see it in context.  At 11:26 he motioned himself as swaying far far far as he continued talking about how he would have to play it "one buttock" on the piano.  In this case he says, "I'm going to play it all the way through...And what you're going to see is one-buttock playing."  It means watch for when he leans over (onto one buttock) so he's squarely above the last chord (which is very low on the keyboard)."

You can see him actually do this, as he says he will.  He leans at the very end (onto one buttock) at 14:45 (start watching at about 14:35).

Note that this is in no way a standard "thing to say in piano lingo".  It's Zander's way of teaching a philosophy about piano playing:  allow oneself to feel and be moved by the music, and find how that translates into your own proper form.

Zander is saying that there's still a need to be sure that form (body position) is properly conveying the function (musical meaning). It's not just letting the music take over the body; it's allowing the body to move properly according to the meaning of the music. The former is just wild abandon, the latter is mind/body harmony. Zander is promoting mind/body harmony as opposed to the mind ruling the body.

Comment: This is an excellent answer; unfortunately it's not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @StoneyB I said exactly the same thing.  This is an anticipatory answer to a modified question. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60263/one-buttock-playing-a-musical-terminology-by-benjamin-zander-how-should-i-tr/60281?noredirect=1#comment115546_60263.

Answer (score 0):

In English the word *hip* may be used to include the buttock, and in fact in sitting on one buttock you are moving your weight to the hip joint. If the word for *hip* is used this way you may use it for *buttock* wherever it occurs without misrepresenting the sense.

But it won't be nearly so amusing.